# Custom UITableViewCell Button and RowSelected (iOS/Monotouch)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uibutton

I have a 'Load More' `UIButton` inside a custom `UITableViewCell`. My table also uses a Delegate. I want to reload the table data when this button is clicked. I have noticed that when I click the button, nothing happens. But when I click on the area around the button i.e. the actual Cell, the Delegate gets the RowSelected event.
I tried using `SetSelected(true,false);` from the button's touch up inside event to see if it would fire the RowSelected event for the delegate, but it didn't.

Can anyone explain me how I can make a button click for a Custom Table cell fire the actual Row Selected event? If this isn't a viable option, is there a better way to 'Load more data' other than placing the button inside a custom table view cell?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I do use ContentView.AddSubView as shown in the code below. Please note I'm using Monotouch, but the logic is the same:

```
            public LoadMoreCell (string reuseCellIdentifier)
        :base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseCellIdentifier)
    {
        SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

        _btnLoadMore = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        _btnLoadMore.Frame = new RectangleF(10,5,300,30);
        _btnLoadMore.SetTitle("Load More", UIControlState.Normal);
        _btnLoadMore.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        ContentView.AddSubview(_btnLoadMore);


    }
```

I have a TableDelegate that has a RowSelected method where I reload the data...however, the RowSelected only gets fired when I click the actual row.

Comment: did you override the layoutSubViews Method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have added the uibutton as

```
[self addSubView:yourButton];
```

instead use :-

```
[self.contentView addSubview:yourButton];
```

and all the other controls of your custom cell.
Do this in the initializer of your custom cell :-

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {}
```

Answer (score 0):

make a custom UITableViewDataSource for your table
and when you hit the button 'Load more', call a method of this datasource to add other data to the list of the datasource, add this datasource to your table and make sure to reload the data of the table

```
this.tblData.ReloadData ();
```